# How to disable a key in another program?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing a program with visual C++ that should change some keyboard keys in a game.

I used
`kHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,setkey,NULL,0);` 
to know the keys are pressed in computer and
`FindWindow()`
to find the game that I should process my code to get the keys are pressed in that game.

But I need to disable some keys for example when space is clicked I need to prevent the game to know space is clicked. Actually disable space in that game what should I do. I searched a lot but I got nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read carefully [LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are answers.

Basically you need in your `LowLevelKeyboardProc` implementation (`setkey`?):

1. Check `wParam` for `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages
2. Check `vkCode` from structure pointed by `lParam` for `VK_SPACE`
3. If 1 and 2 are both true return non-zero to eat processed message

Comment: Thank You very much my problem was in returning non-zero

Answer (score 2):

This systemwide keyboard hook might meet you halfway. It detects the space key.

code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#pragma comment( lib, "user32.lib" )

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HHOOK hKeyboardHook;

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardEvent (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD SHIFT_key=0;
    DWORD CTRL_key=0;
    DWORD ALT_key=0;

    if  ((nCode == HC_ACTION) &&   ((wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) ||  (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)))      
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hooked_key =    *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        DWORD dwMsg = 1;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.scanCode << 16;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.flags << 24;
        char lpszKeyName[1024] = {0};
        lpszKeyName[0] = '[';

        int i = GetKeyNameText(dwMsg,   (lpszKeyName+1),0xFF) + 1;
        lpszKeyName[i] = ']';

        int key = hooked_key.vkCode;

        SHIFT_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
        CTRL_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL);
        ALT_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU);


        if (key ==VK_SPACE)   //Space key detected, do stuff
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Space key detected", "Keyboard hook", MB_OK); 
             return 1;

        }


    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook,    nCode,wParam,lParam);
}

void MessageLoop()
{
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) 
    {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI my_HotKey(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (!hInstance) hInstance = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR) lpParm); 
    if (!hInstance) return 1;

    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx (  WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC) KeyboardEvent,   hInstance,  NULL    );
    MessageLoop();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThread;

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)   my_HotKey, (LPVOID) argv[0], NULL, &dwThread);



    if (hThread) return WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);
    else return 1;

}
```